# How to delete list items automatically after a delay in python?

Tags: python

If i have a list 
for example : 
`num=[1,2,3,4]`
and i want to delete 
`list[0]` 
every 2 second, so after 2 second list in num is `num = [2,3,4]` and 2 second after it will be `num =[2,3]`
how can i do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do it using `time.sleep`, and `del` to remove the first element:

```
for i in range(len(num)):
    time.sleep(2)
    del num[0]
```

Comment: Additionally, if you also want to do something with that first value, you could use `num.pop(0)`

Comment: Also, although performance is probably not an issue here, for a long list you might want to use collections.deque instead of a list: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.deque

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is using `list.pop()`, as follows:

```
import time
num=[1,2,3,4]
while num:
  num.pop(0)
  time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 3):

This does so, until eventually it runs out of elements to remove.

```
import time

num = [1, 2, 3, 4]
while num:
    time.sleep(2)
    del num[0]
    print (num)
```

Comment: Might be tempted to make that `while num` instead of `while True` - that way the loop will exit gracefully (or not attempt to delete from an empty list to start with) when it's empty rather than raise an exception.

Comment: Good idea. Done

Answer (score 0):

Try this code !

Use `sleep` function by importing `time` file & `del` command to remove the element from list.

**Code :**

```
import time

num = [1,2,3,4]
for i in num:
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Delete item ", i)
    del i
```

**Output :**

```
Delete item  1                                                                                                          
Delete item  2                                                                                                          
Delete item  3                                                                                                          
Delete item  4
```